# Put one caption for multiple subfigure

Tags: captions

I have some figures like this: [image] I want to use one caption for each pair like the figure.

Note: I can not use the subfigure and subcaption package.
Best

Comment: No:) I also asked this question some days ago.

Comment: Why then you ask it again? This question is duplicate!

Comment: If the previous question and its solutions solved my question, I did not ask the question again. These two questions are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since your figure look to have same width and height as each other maybe you could group them inside the same figure environment :

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Your text

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
    \tikz\node[minimum height=\linewidth,minimum width=\linewidth,draw]{figure 1};
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
    \tikz\node[minimum height=\linewidth,minimum width=\linewidth,draw]{figure 2};
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two figures one caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]